# Why does $var='' change $_SESSION['var']?

Tags: php

Weird behaviour in 5.3.13?

I have a variable $isguest that has been stored into $_SESSION['isguest'] in the previous page (previous.php). On the current page (main.php) I want to determine if the user has been redirected from previous.php (therefore is a guest) or he has logged in directly into main.php. Then something funny happens:

```
session_start();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION); // At this point, [isguest] => 1;
echo "</pre>";

    $isguest = '';      // this should have nothing to do with the SESSION variable that happens to have the same name, should it?

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION); // At this point, [isguest] => 0;
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: If it changed the session variable to an empty string, I would suspect that `$isguest` is a reference variable. But since setting the regular variable to an empty string changes the session variable to a number, I can't think of any way this could be happening.

Comment: BTW, get in the habit of using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, the results are more precise.

Comment: can we see the place where `$_SESSION['isguest']` is set and interacted with?

Comment: Is `register_globals` on in your php.ini?

Comment: @Barmar or use a proper debugger (XDebug / Zend Debugger)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not disapproving your way, but I think you could do this instead.

Instead of *['isguest']* , make a Session called *['LoggedIn']*, Set that to 0(false). Which would be, Not logged in, therefor he/she's a guest.

When the user logs in, Set that to 1(true). So the user is indeed logged in.

I hope this kind-of helps you.